# Ionic 3 background location not working. Background location not updating on firebase when APP goes to background

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

### app.component.ts

constructor(
    platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar, 
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
    public cs:CustomService
    ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

```
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  this.cs.startBackgroundLocation();
});
```

}

---

### cucstomservice.ts

```
    setInterval(()=>{
        this.count = this.count+1;
        firebase.database().ref('test/').set(this.count);
    },3000)

    let options = {
      frequency: 3000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.watchLocationMode()

    this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {
      console.log(position);
      if(position){
        firebase.database().ref('testingData/')
        .set({
            lat:position.coords.latitude,
            lng:position.coords.longitude
        }).then(()=>{})
      }

      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Does this happen for both android and ios ?

Comment: I am trying only in android but does not work